# Optional int parameter 'rating' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I am using mvc spring along with mysql workbench for my project. On one of my pages the user can add a comment and a rating to the shop. The problem is, I want the rating and commenting to be optional - commenting is, rating isn't. And when I use my controller like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value={"/", "/shop"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String kmetija11(@RequestParam(value = "rating", required = false) int mark,
                        @RequestParam(value = "content", required = false) String comment) {
    markDao.addMark(mark);
    commentDao.addComment(comment);
    return "redirect:/input";
}
```

I get rating value from this form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/shop">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" value="Add comment ..." name="content"/>
        <ul class="rate-area">
            <input type="radio" id="5-star" name="rating" value="5" />
            <label for="5-star">5 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="4-star" name="rating" value="4" />
            <label for="4-star">4 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="3-star" name="rating" value="3" />
            <label for="3-star">3 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="2-star" name="rating" value="2" />
            <label for="2-star">2 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="1-star" name="rating" value="1" />
            <label for="1-star">1 star</label>
        </ul>
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" >Add comment / mark</button>
</form>
```

So what happens is, if I don't put --> value = "rating", required  = false) <--
it says that the parameter is required since default value is true. But if I put the code as it is now, I get this error: http://prntscr.com/jtppgo

If anyone has any idea on what do to, I'd be glad to hear the answer.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because int is a primitive data type which has default value zero.

Please use wrapper class `Integer` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not necessarily solve the issue. When a value is transferred via an HTTP protocol its not a type, its a string and turning it into "Integer" instead didn't do anything. So in my case I had to add

```
@RequestParam (required=false, defaultValue= "10") int integerExample
```

so I set a default value as a string. Now it works like a charm :)

Comment: this is not a good solution, might cause problems in this case - good practise is using boxed types when dealing with serialization - may it be database, rest-api or xml to name the few.

Comment: Guess it depends on your project and how it is being used. But this was working fine for me at least. Good to know it can cause problems for some!

Answer (score 0):

Just change int into Integer and you'r done. Primitives cant be null, Objects can..